# Calling variables from class (DateTime)

Tags: c#, class, datetime, methods

I need to call my datetime variable from another class,

this is the code for querying with date condition

```
static DataTable GetCustomerRecords(DateTime date, DateTime date2)
        {
            var connSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"];
            {

                string CN = connSettings.ConnectionString;
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(CN);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select value1, value2, value3, date2 from dummy table where date1 >= CAST(@startDate AS DATE) and date2 <= CAST(@endDate AS DATE)", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", date2);
                MySqlDataAdapter data = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                conn.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                data.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }

        }

 public object QueryRecords(DateTime date, DateTime date2)
        {
            DataTable table = GetCustomerRecords();
            return table;
        }
```

My DatePicker 1 and 2 ValueChanged

```
 GetRecords Retrieve = new GetRecords();
 private void datePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Retrieve.GetCustomerRecords(date)/error here of course
    }

    private void datePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Retrieve.GetCustomerRecords(date2)/error here of course

    }
```

i don't know how to do proper calling of method, im new at this.

Comment: Well you're trying to only pass a single value, but the method has two parameters. Perhaps you should pass in `datePicker1.Value` and `datePicker2.Value` in both cases?

Comment: thank you i have tried (date, date2) it works but it no data has been shown.

Comment: Well it's hard to know whether that's appropriate or not, as we can't even see a declaration of `date` and `date2`. Are they automatically updated with the values of your pickers? Have you debugged into the code?

Comment: yes i have debugged the code and also my query works, tried it first on mysql, i have declared date and date 2 in both public object QueryRecords and static DataTable GetCustomerRecords, im wondering if this is the reason why im not getting a data? i dont know what's the correct method to do this.

Comment: Just declaring the variables doesn't mean you're passing appropriate values in. I note that you're not *doing* anything with the `DataTable` returned from `GetCustomerRecords` in the code you've shown us - if that's all your code, how did you expect anything to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Your `static` method accepts two `DateTime` arguments:

```
static DataTable GetCustomerRecords(DateTime date, DateTime date2)
```

While you're only passing one each time:

```
Retrieve.GetCustomerRecords(date)
Retrieve.GetCustomerRecords(date2)
```

You need to pass both `DateTime` arguments each time you call your method:

```
Retrieve.GetCustomerRecords(date, date2)
```

Comment: you are right, i tried this it works but no data has been fetched. 

maybe this is the culprit? 

 public object QueryRecords(DateTime date, DateTime date2)
        {
            DataTable table = GetCustomerRecords();
            return table;
        }

Comment: i have have declared datetime date and datetime date2 in public object QueryRecords(DateTime date, DateTime date2) and also static DataTable GetCustomerRecords(DateTime date, DateTime date2)

Comment: @KevinRodriguez I'm sorry, I'm not following. What does this have to do with the original question? If your data isn't being retrieved from the database, it could be many things along the way. Have you debugged your code?

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm asking about the correct method of passing arguments between forms, you see i have declared datetime in both public object QueryRecords and DataTable GetCustomerRecords im wondering if this is the reason as to why im getting no data, i have debugged the code, yes and also my query works i have tried it in mysql before putting it in c#

Answer (score 0):

**This will be your form (code behind) where you will have three events. Two to select the start date and end date. The last is for your button click event to call your other class.**

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.StartDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
}

private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.EndDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataTable results = GetCustomerRecords.GetCustomerRecord(this.StartDate, this.EndDate);
}




public static class GetCustomerRecords
{
  public static DataTable GetCustomerRecord(DateTime date, DateTime date2)
  {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnStr"].ConnectionString;
    string query = @"select 
                      value1, 
                      value2, 
                      value3, 
                      date2 
                     from TABLE 
                     where date1 BETWEEN 
                     CAST(@startDate AS DATE) and CAST(@endDate AS DATE)";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", date);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", date2);
      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
      adapter.Fill(dt);
    }

     return dt;
   }
}
```

Comment: You also need properties to store off your date time values somewhere to pass them to your other class.

Comment: hello, i can't get it to work, i cant seem to call the method from the other form, its not appearing when i type GetCustomerRecords

Comment: Make sure the class is accessible (public).

Comment: Also, I just realized a bug in what I posted. Make sure the method is named something different than the class itself also.

Comment: string startDate;
string endDate;
DataTable results = GetCustomerRecords.GetCustomerRecords(this.startDate, this.endDate);

im getting overloaded method match. invalid arguments

Comment: This may be a database issue. Make sure your sql query works in sql first and pulls data, then copy and paste it into your c# code. You are trying to get all records that are between those two dates right?