# Call DateTime argument from Class

Tags: c#, class, datetime, methods

I need to call a query between dates

```
class MemberSched
 { 
 static DataTable GetMemberRecords(DateTime date, DateTime date2)
    {
        var connSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"];
        {
            string CN = connSettings.ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(CN);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4 from sometable where datefrom >= CAST(@startDate AS DATE) and dateto <= CAST(@endDate AS DATE)", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", date2);
            MySqlDataAdapter data = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            data.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
 }

    public object QueryBetweenDate()
        {
            DataTable table = GetMemberRecords();
            return table;
        }

        private void datePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //i don't know what should i put in here
        }


        private void datePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //i don't know what should i put in here
        }
```

i'm stumped over this, as i'm still new in C#, my query works fine as i have tried it in mysql beforehand, the date arguments on GetMemberRecords i dont know if that is right and also im getting error on public object QueryBetweenDate()

Comment: the GetMemberRecords is static so i thought if i call it through QueryBetweenDate() which is public then i can call this method from outside the class, if this is wrong im leaning towards a correct usage with this kind of scenario

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your earlier question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850817/calling-variables-from-class-datetime). Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is close, but not quite. Try this:

```
select value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4 from sometable where datefrom BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate
```

You shouldn't have to cast the datetime variables since the connector will automatically do it as long as you pass in DateTime objects to the parameters. The BETWEEN SQL operator then takes care of making sure it is between the right dates.

Other than the casts, there wasn't anything technically wrong with the original SQL, but BETWEEN is a little easier to understand.

Comment: I apologize for it not being a complete answer, there was another answer that was deleted that I was expanding on.

Comment: im sorry i forgot to include that im using MySQL which i read somewhere that i need to cast the dates for MySQL

Comment: You would if you were passing in string representations of a date (like in the MySQL Workbench), but since you are passing into the connector actual datetime objects the connector takes care of putting them in the right format.

Comment: my query works if i put it directly in the form not in class, i just want to implement classes and methods in my program, i'm still new at this.